# Why are my exponential numbers being rounded? (C language)

Tags: c

I am getting unexpected results when printing some doubles.  Some rounding is taking place, and I'm not sure why.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
double d1 = 0;
double d2 = 0;

d1 = 1.2345678901234567e16;
d2 = 112233445566778899.0;

printf("d1: %.0lf\n", d1);
printf("d2: %.0lf\n", d2);

return 0;
}
```

The results of running the program are:

```
d1: 12345678901234568
d2: 112233445566778900
```

In the first case, I'm not sure why the last digit (the 7) got rounded to an 8, if there are no numbers after it.
In the second case, I also don't know why the number in the hundreds position got rounded.  Doubles should accomodate numbers much larger than these without rounding.
Thanks

Comment: Read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: `"%lf"` is an invalid specifier for printf, use `"%f"` for `double` (and `float`) and `"%Lf"` for `long double.`

Comment: @pmg: Actually it's valid but the `l` modifier has no effect on the `f` specifier. I believe this is similar to the useless `h` and `hh` modifiers: they're for consistency with `scanf`.

Comment: `"%lf"` is indeed valid C99, thanks @R.. -- *however it was Undefined Behaviour in C89 :)*

Answer (score 3):

Not "much larger" - in fact you're right at the limit for "accuracy". A double has 53 bits of accuracy. Your first number is about 10^16, which would need *about* 16/(log 2) = 53.15 bits to be accurate to within an integer.

Answer (score 3):

“Doubles should accomodate numbers much larger than these without rounding.”  Why do you think so?

An IEEE standard `double` (which is what you are using) has 53 bits (binary digits) of precision.

Go to Wolfram Alpha and ask it for [the binary representation of 12345678901234567](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=12345678901234567+in+binary).  It will tell you that the binary form has 54 digits.  Therefore it cannot be represented exactly as a `double`.

Your second number requires 57 digits, so it too cannot be represented exactly.

Comment: My reasoning was the following.  I looked up "range of double data type in C" in Google, and found that the range of a double value was 1.7 x 10^308.  To me that was an immense number, much bigger than 16 digits.  So my 16-digit number was safe and would not suffer rounding.  I guess I am misunderstanding what is meant by 1.7 x 10^308.

Answer (score 2):

`Doubles should accomodate numbers much larger than these without rounding` - yes, if they are powers of 2. If there is a large distance between the leftest and rightest 1 in their binary presentation, they will be rounded.

Answer (score 1):

A 64 bit double only has 16 or so decimal digits of precision  - you're simply reaching the precision limits of the data type